# How does web server know access application metadata (for example, list of available routes)?

Tags: nginx, webserver

I recognize this may be a stupid question, but still - how do web servers know what routes does application have? 
Popular web-servers (Apache, Nginx, IIS) support web apps written in different languages and various frameworks, so there must be a standard way to access application's metadata, or some conventions that are common.

Comment: They don't. Usually they proxies almost every request to application. The main exception is static files (images, js, css) and you have some rules in server config to distinguish these files.

Comment: Here is nginx example for wordpress http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress

Comment: @AlexeyTen really? I'm trying hard to understand how one can send a web request to a jar file or a DLL

Comment: client sends HTTP request to the server. server then proxies request to the application - but application can be anything, DLL, jar, Ruby/Python script, etc. my question is - how is it possible to ask all this kinds of apps "give me a response for such url" in a uniform way (meaning it does not matter to the server what language or runtime my app is written in)?

Comment: Server passes to application full request from client including url, headers (cookies), etc. Fastcgi/http protocols does not depends on "what language or runtime my app is written in".

Comment: I must be really dumb, I can't understand how one can pass a HTTP request to a Python script (just as an example)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52181/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-chester89)